# Data Structure alternatives to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, data-structures, game-development

Me and a friend are currently in the process of making a Discord Bot (Node.js and Discord.js) that is meant to allow players to play a Text RPG with a semi-persistent world which was created by another person (a 'Dungon Master' of sorts). The 'DM' creates the story using some tools in a web interface while the player would later use the bot to navigate this world any time at his speed.

Our current idea is to create a JSON 'gamefile' of the world and have the player hand that to the Discord bot, who then allows the player to interact with the gamefile.

**Our problem:**
After some testing, we learned that JSON would limit things a lot or be insanely long and complicated. Not just for the file but also for the DM to create.
eg.: If player moves a dresser to find a hidden passage, the next player to go there should find the dresser already moved. We now need 2 states of this room in the JSON file. If a player takes a book with them, we need 4 states. Another item and we need 8. This clearly gets out of hand VERY fast and that's assuming every item only has 2 states.

**My question:**
Is there an alternative data structure or way to save a 'gamefile' what maybe allows for more flexibility in that regard? Or is this just an inherent problem with the concept?

Comment: maybe you can check `YAML`?

Comment: JSON isn't really your problem. JSON is just a serialisation format that you could substitute for YAML or XML or CSV or whatever else. The problem is how you want to express your state exactly. It's not clear what exactly would lead to the duplication of states here. How exactly did you plan on expressing a moved dresser and such that would lead to two states…?

Comment: JSON as a format is very efficient, so that's not really what you're up against here. It's more about figuring out how to recreate a game state, which is a separate problem from what format you store it in. If you can save each switch (dresser opened, etc) in order and recreate the state from the series of decisions in a predictable manner where the results were always the same then that would probably be the shortest save file.

Comment: @deceze I see we're having the same kind of night hah. Cheers

Comment: @deceze 
For example player walks into room and gets the prompt: "you walk into room and see a dresser". Player then moves dresser revealing a door.
Next player walks in should then get the prompt: "You walk into the room and see a dresser next to a door".
That mean the room needs to have 2 states. 1 where the dresser is still in front of the door and one where its not. Depending on the state, the player gets served different prompts when entering.If another significant variation is introduced to the room, youd need 4 room states with 4 prompts etcetc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try out ink, a narrative scripting language. I stumbled upon it some years ago and it looks like it is exactly made for describing narrative content together with states and all that stuff; but I personally have never worked with it, so I don't know how it feels/behaves exactly.

It basically allows you to write down the dialogue and descriptions, but also allows to incorporate Variables, Choices and a Logic Flow.

You could incorporate missing books, moved dressers etc. as conditional text in the description of a room, that would only be rendered if that condition is met and use the dialog functionality for navigation and interaction.

The official website gives a good overview, including some examples: https://www.inklestudios.com/ink/

There is also a node.js implementation of ink: https://github.com/y-lohse/inkjs